# What Kind of a Pyhsical Setup I Need to Test a UDP Multicasting Software

Tags: udp, multicast, ethernet

I can deliver normal UDP messages between two computers using a direct ethernet connection using my software. But I couldn't do the same for multicasting messages, I've tried other softwares that can send and receive multicast UDP messages and they didn't work as well. So I thought and wanted to ask if a direct Ethernet connection is a proper pyhsical setup or not. And if not what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a direct ethernet supports multicast.  As opposed to an NBMA network like frame relay (rare these days) which does not support multicast for example.

Make sure you are not actually using a switch (which is a bridge) that has IGMP snooping enabled.  IGMP snooping will not propagate multicast to nodes that have not sent an IGMP join (assuming your software does not do the join).

Comment: I am not using a swtich, I directly connect two computers via Ethernet but my normal UDP softwares works correctly, I can't send or receive messages when I try to use UDP multicasting.

Comment: Can your post a wireshark capture?

Comment: the problem was the usb to ethernet converter that i used because my computer doesn't have an ethernet port. It worked on another pc. Thanks for the support

Comment: Interesting; thanks for following up.